# PHP condition checking for country

Tags: php

Hi have to check for 2 countries in order to setup a shipping cost. (These values are previously assigned via a dropdown list). Here's my PHP condition, it doesn't seem to work. Can someone please help me with the syntax if I'm doing a mistake?

```
<?php
for( $y = 0; $y < count( $contentsArray ); $y++ )
{

  $itemArray = explode( ":", $contentsArray[ $y ] );

  $price = number_format( $itemArray[ 2 ] * $itemArray[ 1 ], 2 );
  $subtotal += $price;

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td class='item_col'>" . $itemArray[ 0 ] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='description_col'>" . $itemArray[ 3 ] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='quantity_col'>" . $itemArray[ 1 ] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='price_col'>$ " . $price . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

// calculate the shipping  



if( $subtotal > 500 )
  $shipping = 0.00;
```

// ---- This is where I'm trying to add my condition and bugs ------

```
else if ( $country == "Canada" )
  $shipping = 10.00;
else if ( $country == "USA" )
  $shipping = 10.00;
```

// ---- Above where I'm trying to add my condition ------

else
      $shipping = 15.00;

```
$shipping = number_format( $shipping, 2 );  




// calculate the tax and total for the cart
$gst = number_format( ( $subtotal + $shipping ) * 0.06, 2 );
$total = $subtotal + $shipping + $gst;

// update the totals in the db
$cartData->totals = $shipping . "|" . $gst . "|" . $total;
$updateSuccess = updateCartTotals( $merchant, $cartData );
?>

</tbody>
</table>
<br />

<div id="invoice_totals">
  <div id="totals">
    $ <?=number_format( $subtotal, 2 )?><br />
    $ <?=number_format( $shipping, 2 )?><br />
    $ <?=number_format( $gst, 2 )?><br />
    <span class="total">$ <?=number_format( $total, 2 )?></span>
  </div>

  <div id="headings">
    <strong>subtotal:</strong><br />
    <strong>shipping:</strong><br />
    <strong>tax:</strong><br />
    <span class="total">total:</span>
  </div>

  <div id="print">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/cart/buttons/print.gif" width="41" height="41" border="0" onmouseover="this.src='images/cart/buttons/print_ov.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='images/cart/buttons/print.gif'" /></a>
  </div>

  <div class="cleaner"></div>

  <div id="back">
    <a href="shipping.html"><img src="images/cart/buttons/back.gif" width="58" height="58" border="0" onmouseover="this.src='images/cart/buttons/back_ov.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='images/cart/buttons/back.gif'" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="cleaner"></div>
</div>

</div>

<div id="shipping_information">
<p>
  <strong>Shipping to:</strong><br />
  <?=$customerData->firstName . " " . $customerData->lastName?><br />
  <?=$customerData->address?><br />
  <?=$customerData->city . ", " . $customerData->province?><br />
  <?=getCountryName( $customerData->country )?><br />
  <?=$customerData->postalCode?>
</p>

...
```

Comment: Everything looks fine to me, could you explain "doesn't seem to work"? What should it be doing, and what is it actually doing that you think is wrong?

Comment: Given that structure, it will only check for the countries if the subtotal is below 500. What's the subtotal at when you try this out?

Comment: I don't see an error assuming that those two countries also qualify for the free shipping on orders over 500 whatevers.  If not, and your testing satisfies that condition, then that's your problem, and that conditional will need to be demoted to below the country checks.  Can you give us the output of `var_dump($country);` ? You might want to use something like `if (!stristr($country,'canada'))`, but it would help if we had a little more info.

Comment: Using Mistabell's function below... I'm always getting 0.00

Comment: What you getting for subtotal when do this? Print out the price in the loop and see if the correct prices are coming out as well.

Comment: Matt, I think my country statement is the issue... everything works correctly until I add this:  else if
                           ( $country == "Canada" )
                            $shipping = 10.00;

                        else if
                           ( $country == "USA" )
                            $shipping = 10.00;

Answer (score 0):

To let us help you further, add the following two additions to your code (exactly where I added them below). Run it, then paste the "DEBUG" messages here on your StackOverflow question.

```
<?php
for( $y = 0; $y < count( $contentsArray ); $y++ )
{

  $itemArray = explode( ":", $contentsArray[ $y ] );

  $price = number_format( $itemArray[ 2 ] * $itemArray[ 1 ], 2 );
  $subtotal += $price;

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td class='item_col'>" . $itemArray[ 0 ] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='description_col'>" . $itemArray[ 3 ] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='quantity_col'>" . $itemArray[ 1 ] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='price_col'>$ " . $price . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

// calculate the shipping  

// ADDITION #1
echo "DEBUG: subtotal is $subtotal;<br>DEBUG: country is $country";
if( $subtotal > 500 )
  $shipping = 0.00;
// ---- This is where I'm trying to add my condition and bugs ------

else if ( $country == "Canada" )
  $shipping = 10.00;
else if ( $country == "USA" )
  $shipping = 10.00;
// ---- Above where I'm trying to add my condition ------

// ADDITION #2
else $shipping = 15.00;
echo "DEBUG: shipping is $shipping";
```

Comment: Here's the debug output: 
DEBUG: subtotal is 12.95;
DEBUG: country is DEBUG: shipping is 15

Comment: That means this code is working fine. Your error is happening sometime **after** the line `else $shipping = 15.00;`. Keep echoing the value of `$shipping` throughout your code until you find out where it's being changed to 0.

Comment: Is there a chance it's the Country value not being picked up?

Comment: Well, from your output, the `Country` value is definitely not being picked up, but that doesn't explain why `$shipping` is ending up as `0.00`.

Comment: Willell, the $shipping value is working ok (it's below $500). It however can pick up the country value... any tips?

Comment: *edited - I meant, it can't pickup the $country value "Canada" or "USA" so won't display the 10.00 accordingly

Comment: I'd need to see the rest of your code, specifically any code that deals with `$country`. The code you included in your question doesn't show `$country` being defined.

Comment: Willell, the country does show a little lower on the page when I'm on this page. It is being collected from a previous page and shows here. We should be able evaluate the defined value above. Somehow, it still doesn't work

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on what you're saying, but it sounds like you may need to take a closer look at that "previous page" you mentioned. Again, it would really help to consider the entire script as a whole.